# Error when trying to import PuLP - ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)

Tags: python, python-3.8, pulp, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running into a strange error when trying to load puLp in python 3.8

```
>>> import pulp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ra7555ga/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .pulp import *
  File "/home/ra7555ga/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 102, in <module>
    from .solvers import *
  File "/home/ra7555ga/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/solvers.py", line 35, in <module>
    from time import clock
ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)
```

Anyone that has had a similar situation?

I'm in an Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine and installed PuLP 2.3 as `sudo pip3 install pulp`

Comment: `time.clock` has been deprecated for a while, and removed in Python 3.8.  PuLP has apparently been updated to fix this (see https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/pull/237), but maybe that change hasn't made it to a released version yet.

Comment: The change did make it to the release, it's been a long time. Usually, these issues come when using an old version of pulp (anaconda for example didn't have the latest version). You can always try with the development version but I suspect there you're not using version 2.3

Comment: in fact I know for a fact that's not pulp 2.3 for several reasons: (1) the pulp files correspond to version 1.6 and (2) the fact that you're using sudo to install pulp, which installs the library in the system python interpreter but you're using the users' python interpreter (in `.local`). Try installing pulp without sudo: `pip3 install pulp --user`

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the latest version of PuLP. That's because you're installing pulp in the wrong place (by using sudo).

I know it's version 1.6 because:
(1) the pulp files in the errors correspond to version 1.6 and
(2) the fact that you're using sudo to install pulp, which installs the library in the system python interpreter but you're using the users' python interpreter (in `.local`).

The solution is installing pulp in your user python directory by doing:

```
pip3 install pulp --user
```